# Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) build fails to Deploy Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a solution that builds and publishes successfully on my local machine. I have created a build definition on Team Services (using the new framework - not XAML builds) that mimics my local steps and then runs an Azure Deployment build step. The Azure Deployment build step is consistently failing on the following command:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -ServiceName website -Package C:\a\1\s\WebsiteSolution\Azure\bin\Production\ServiceDefinition.csdef -Configuration C:\a\1\s\WebsiteSolution\Azure\bin\Production\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg -Slot Production -Label 20160801.4 -ExtensionConfiguration <extensions>
```

With the following error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.ComputeCloudException: BadRequest : Package conversion failed. Detailed error information: FileFormatException. ---> Hyak.Common.CloudException: BadRequest : Package conversion failed. Detailed error information: FileFormatException. at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.DeploymentOperationsExtensions.UpgradeBySlot(IDeploymentOperations operations, String serviceName, DeploymentSlot deploymentSlot, DeploymentUpgradeParameters parameters) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.ServiceManagementBaseCmdlet.ExecuteClientActionNewSM[TResult](Object input, String operationDescription, Func`1 action, Func`3 contextFactory) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.ServiceManagementBaseCmdlet.ExecuteClientActionNewSM[TResult](Object input, String operationDescription, Func`1 action, Func`3 contextFactory)
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong or how to diagnose the problem with the generated package that makes it invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Cloud Service Deployment task requires a CsPkg package file. But according to your error logs, you are specifying a csdef file for the "CsPkg" option. Update your build definition to set the "CsPkg" path correctly and then queue the build again.
[image]